# cant boot from usb formatted on linux with dd

Tags: windows, bootable

I have an ASUS laptop which runs Manjaro 20.0.3.
I have created a bootable usb stick from an ISO like this:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=~/Windows/win7u.iso of=/dev/sdc status=progress oflag=sync
```

When I access the boot menu and select my usb drive, instead of booting from it, it just boots Manjaro from the main disk. I have also tried a different laptop, which does the same thing. I don't know why this is happening. I have created a bootable usb with dd before, that's how I installed Manjaro, it seems the ISO file is at fault, but the ISO is not corrupted or broken, because I was able to create a VM from it with QEMU.

Comment: Have you set the `boot` flag (with `gparted`) on `/dev/sdc`?

Comment: @waltinator I don't use gparted. Does setting the boot flag make the first partition bootable? I think I might be able to accomplish that, when I'm home.

Comment: Click on my userid ( the blue `waltinator`just below this comment) and read my "Dual Boot Advice", and the Wikipedia pages.